# Video Modal with wanted Slider (carousel) function

Tags: youtube, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, carousel

I have code for a Modal to display a video and auto stop on close.
We use Bootstrap 3.3.7
We want to be able to get to the next and previous video without closing the modal either by "Arrows" or a button to the next one.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Title of the Video Section</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a class="video-btn" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bXlalGvxkaY" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="https://youtu.be/bXlalGvxkaY" role="button" title="Learn more about Jeff Henne fireside chat video"><img alt="Jeff Henne fireside chat video" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/bXlalGvxkaY/maxresdefault.jpg"></a>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h3><a class="video-btn" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bXlalGvxkaY" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" role="button" title="Learn more about Jeff Henne fireside chat video">This is the Happy Title - also linked</a></h3>
            <p>This is the copy or short blurb about the video.... This is the copy or short blurb about the video....</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
    
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a class="video-btn" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9G69n11o3z8" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="https://youtu.be/9G69n11o3z8" role="button"><img alt="Cleopatra's Lost Tomb (Full Episode) | Lost Treasures of Egypt" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/9G69n11o3z8/maxresdefault.jpg" title="Learn more about ........... video"></a>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h3><a class="video-btn test3" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9G69n11o3z8" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" role="button" title="Learn more about ........... video">Cleopatra's Lost Tomb (Full Episode) | Lost Treasures of Egypt</a></h3>
            <p>See some fun stuff........................</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a class="video-btn" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WCrmkX35Xks" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="https://youtu.be/WCrmkX35Xks" role="button" title="Learn more about ........... video"><img alt="Jeff Henne fireside chat video" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WCrmkX35Xks/maxresdefault.jpg"></a>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h4><a class="video-btn test4" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WCrmkX35Xks" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" role="button" title="Learn more about ........... video">Test</a></h4>
            <p>Copy here ...... Copy here ...... Copy here ...... Copy here ...... Copy here ...... Copy here ......</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>




<!-- Modal Code - Auto Filled -->
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe allowfullscreen id="video" name="video" src="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" ></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded btn-md ml-4" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Modal Code - Auto Filled // -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script><!-- video modal functions =-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
        var $videoSrc;  
        $('.video-btn').click(function() {
            $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
        });
        console.log($videoSrc); 
          
        // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            
        // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video
        $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" ); 
        })
          
        // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
        $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            // stop video
            $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc); 
        }) 

        // document ready  
    });

</script>
```

I have tried a couple ways to do this with but to no avail.
Searched a options but either didn't format correctly or was sample was for modals that were not created with the data-src.